# Сортировка по стилю

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть такой код:

```
<div>  
<iframe></iframe>  
<iframe></iframe>  
<iframe class="active"></iframe>  
<iframe></iframe>  
</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы при клике на кнопку получилось такое:

```
<div>  
<iframe class="active"></iframe>  
<iframe></iframe>  
<iframe></iframe>  
<iframe></iframe>  
</div>
```

То есть iframe active поднимался на первое место.
Но есть еще одна проблема: надо, чтобы оно перемещало и не меняло содержимое. Я много перепробовал вариантов, но оно действовало так: удаляло элемент и создавало его в том месте, каком надо. А нужно, чтобы просто перемещало.
Помогите, пожалуйста, я все перерыл и не знаю, как сделать. (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перемещать элемент в DOM нельзя,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8318401/815386

но можно менять его позицию с css

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16021153/815386

в новых модных браузерах можно использовать flexbox, примерно так:

```
.container {
  display: flex;

}
.active {
    order: -1;
    border-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nLpopqkc/1/

Comment: Извините, но мне не нужно визуально, а нужно именно в коде.

Comment: И у меня локальный файл.

Comment: как я сказал, в DOM перемещать нельзя, тут вам никто не поможет (разве что вы найдете рычаги давления на w3c) от того, локальный файл или нет, ничего не меняется. если вам не важно изменение других фреймов, вы можете переместить фреймы, которые стоят до активного в конец, но они перегрузятся.